# Excel Formula to display a files last modified date

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro that displays the last date a file was saved. I have tried several version and cannot get any of them to work. Here is the last one tried and I get `#Name` as the result.

```
Function LastSaved() As Date
    LastSavedTimeStamp = ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time")
End Function
```

Comment: If you type `Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time")` into your Immediate window, what does it print in the window?

Answer (score 1):

`LastSavedTimeStamp` needs to be `LastSaved` and the function needs to be in a normal module:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function LastSaved() As Date
    LastSaved = ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time")
End Function
```

Note that if you use this as a formula in a cell `=LastSaved()` then the date in the cell will not change after saving because the formula does not recalculate. It gets a bit better using `Application.Volatile` but even that does not show the correct date after saving but only after recalculation of any other cell.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function LastSaved() As Date
    Application.Volatile
    LastSaved = ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time")
End Function
```

A probably better option would be the following code in `ThisWorkbook`:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value = Now()
End Sub
```

which writes the date into a cell right before saving. This will always show the correct date.

Comment: The second option works great. Thank You